# Invalid Type for Comparable Implementation

Tags: apex, unit-test, wrapper-class, compile-error, comparable

I am sure this is a simple fix but I can not figure out why my test class can not see my comparable class. The error I am getting is `invalid type: CaseInfo`. Why would this be happening? I am following this example https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm . I was thinking that I have to instantiate the wrapper class in the test method but the example doesn't have the wrapper class instantiated. Is this example missing anything?

Apex Comparable:

```
global with sharing class viewAllCaseCommentsActivitiesController {

    global class CaseInfo implements Comparable{
        public Task taskData {get;set;}
        public Case caseNumber {get;set;}

        public caseInfo(Case caseNumber, Task taskData){
            this.caseNumber = caseNumber;
            this.taskData = taskData;
        }

        global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo)
        {
            CaseInfo caseinfo = (CaseInfo)compareTo;
            Integer returnValue = 0;
            if (taskData.Date_Activity_Logged__c < caseinfo.taskData.Date_Activity_Logged__c) {
                returnValue = 1;
            } else if (taskData.Date_Activity_Logged__c > caseinfo.taskData.Date_Activity_Logged__c) {
                returnValue = -1;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
    public viewAllCaseCommentsActivitiesController() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
static testmethod void test1() {
    Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account Name');
    insert a;
    Case c = new Case(Account = a);
    insert c;
    Task t = new Task(Private__c = FALSE, WhatId = c.Id);
    insert t;
    Account a2 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account Name');
    insert a2;
    Case c2 = new Case(Account = a);
    insert c2;
    CaseComment cc  =  new CaseComment(ParentId = c2.Id);
    insert cc;
    CaseComment cc2  =  new CaseComment(ParentId = c2.Id);
    insert cc2;
    Task t2 = new Task(Private__c = FALSE, WhatId = c.Id);
    insert t2;

    List<CaseInfo> caseList = new List<CaseInfo>(); //error here
    caseList.add(new CaseInfo(c, t));
    caseList.add(new CaseInfo(c2, t));
    caseList.add(new CaseInfo(c2, t2));

    // Sort using the custom compareTo() method
    caseList.sort();

    // Write list contents to the debug log
    System.debug(caseList);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CaseInfo is in the viewAllCaseCommentsActivitiesController class, so you need to use the fully-qualified name:

```
List<viewAllCaseCommentsActivitiesController.CaseInfo> caseList = new List<viewAllCaseCommentsActivitiesController.CaseInfo>();
```

Repeat for the remaining lines in your unit test where you reference CaseInfo.